# Javascript does not allow me to set variable with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, window.open

I have done this several times before but am wondering if perhaps there is a conflict with my bitly class.

I use php to generate a bitly url from long ones. This is stored in a variable called

> $url

I can echo the $url variable and know it works fine. However, when I try and place the into the following javascript function (which is called onclick event), the entire action fails.

```
function fbs_click() {
    var uf="<?php echo $url; ?>";
    var tf=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(uf)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(tf),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    return false;
}
```

if I replace  with an actual URL, i have no problems. Even if I replace with the word "blah", it works. Something about the php echo is throwing it for a loop.

The php echo renders this is source:

var uf=""http://bit.ly/rfEcJl\n"";

Comment: Give us an example of the rendered JS function, and any output from your browser's JavaScript error console. You may just need to do `echo json_encode($url)` instead.

Comment: Did you do a view source to see what's getting echoed ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder - good point, i just noticed it is echoing: "var uf=""http:\/\/bit.ly\/rfEcJl\n"";"

Comment: Well, the duplicated quote marks, the `\n`, and the semicolon in the wrong place are all likely an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that url is not in proper form. So just try to console/alert thr url in "uf" variable, and url in winodw.open(...) statement and then check.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that doing this instead will solve your issue:

```
var uf = <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>;
```

Comment: unfortunately, that did not solve it. I'll try to create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Is the url is of some file in the file system and wrongly it is giving you '\' instead of '/'? in which case JS might crash... I guess.